# Multi domains on same Docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker, magento2

I have a Magento 2 running on docker container and I would like to add a wordpress on the same container using one specific domain for each (blog.site and magento.site). I tried using nginx-proxy but it's not working my websites are not accessible anymore.

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock

  app:
    image: markoshust/magento-nginx:1.13-8
    links:
      - db
      - phpfpm
    volumes: &appvolumes
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer:delegated
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - sockdata:/sock
    environment:
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=magento.site"

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - appwpdata:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=blog.site"

  phpfpm:
    image: markoshust/magento-php:7.2-fpm-2
    links:
      - db
    volumes: *appvolumes

  db:
    image: percona:5.7
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    env_file: env/db.env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./env/config.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

volumes:
  appdata:
  appwpdata:
  dbdata:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Comment: you want to add WP to Magento container or to the same docker-compose? When you remove WP entry it works?

Comment: I want to have both WP and Magento running on the same container so that I can link them using a Magento module. Yes my Magento was working perfectly without the WP.

Comment: your config creates separates containers for WP and Magento. You have to create custom `Dockerfile` and install there WP and Magento if you want to have them running on the same container.

Comment: I'm just starting to use Docker do you have a tutorial on how can I do it ?

Comment: you shouldn't close two apps in one container. So now your config looks Ok, separate container for each app. When you added WP entry everything stop workings? Maybe `jwilder/nginx-proxy` has some problem with multiply `VIRTUAL_HOST` env?

Comment: ok yes my configuration seems ok but none of the website is accessible (magento.site or blog.site) and I don't understand why, I'm getting a website is not accessible error. Thanks !

Comment: When you remove WP entry magento.site is working? And when you remove Magento entry is blog.site working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207576/discussion-between-magentodev-and-d0niek).